# remove output pharentesis in a function

Tags: postgresql, record

I'm trying to run this function and all records in the output have a parenthesis, how can I get rid of them?

the below function simply outputs the records in the loop for debugging, I just want to remove the pharentesis.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.loop_test(_report_id integer)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    _rid RECORD ;
BEGIN
FOR _rid IN
      SELECT id FROM schema.table where id=_report_id
   loop
   raise notice '%',_rid;
   END LOOP;
    
END
$function$
;
```

This is what I get (sample)

```
(1755)
(1789)
(1757)
(649)
(1781)
```

I need just the numbers..

Let me clarify that I would like to use the `_rid` variable on an insert within this function but until I don't get rid of the pharentesis I can't move on.

Comment: Why not declare the function as `returns table (id int)` instead of `returns void`? Then you can get rid of the slow an inefficient `raise notice` and use `select * from loop_test()`

Comment: true, but this is just a debug test, no need to return a table, I just want to use the _rid variable for an insert and it comes with pharentesis

Comment: This is because `_rid` is a `record` and as such represents a tuple of the values returned from the `SELECT`.  In this case you only have a single field in the tuple. Still, to get just the actual field(`id`) do as @Abelisto shows and use `_rid.id`.

Comment: this worked: raise notice '%',_rid.id;
Can you put this as an answer? Thanks!